# How to access the config php values (multidimensional array) to class function in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get the values from config.php  for PHP class function.
I am new to php so i am facing issue to assign it global variable and use it in class functions.

config.php is having the below return statement

```
return [
    'database' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'name' => 'somedb',
        'user' => 'someuser',
        'pass' => 'somepass'
    ],
    'api => [
        'url'=>'apiurl' 
       ]
];
```

I am trying the below implementation;

```
$loadvalues=include_once('config.php');

global url;

url=$loadvalues['api']['url']

Class APILoader{

    function getAccess(){

        //url from config need to be used here
    }

}
```

Comment: is it a framework or core php ?

Comment: it is core php.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at `url=$loadvalues['api']['url'];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the global variable in every scope you wanna use it. You do it with they `global` keyword.

```
function getAccess(){
    global $url;
    //whatever now...
}
```

But you better avoid using global variables. You can inject whatver value you want to the constructor of the class, store it in the class property and use it when needed.

```
$loadvalues=include_once('config.php');


Class APILoader{
    private $url;
    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
    }
    function getAccess(){

        //use $this->url here
    }

}

new APILoader($loadvalues['api']['url']);
```